# Python Calculator over localhost - Unexpected results when getting result

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a "localhost calculator", where you can send any equation over to the server, and the server will then return the result of the equation. For now i'm just printing the result in the server program.

## The Problem

I have a little problem; I get unexpected results, when I run the program. For example: “10 + 45” will evaluate to “65” and that’s not right.

I have a feeling that it’s something simple that I’m missing.

## The Code

Here is my code:

The server `tmServer.py`:

```
"""
   This is the server, that hosts the connection between the client
   and the server.
   This server stores the clients math equation, finds out what kind
   of equation it is, and returns back the final answer to the equation.
"""

import socket
import sys

import exceptions as exc

# Socket for creating a connection.
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = ''

# Try getting the port from the commandline.
try:
    port = int(sys.argv[1])
except IndexError:
    err = True
else:
    err = False

# If err is True, no argument is provided.
# Raise exception.
if err == True:
    msg = "You can't run this in the main with no port argument!"
    raise exc.RunningInMainFileOrNoArgumentException(msg)

# Host the connection with s.bind()
s.bind((host, port))

# Listen after request for connection
# and if so, accept connection.
s.listen(1)
print("Waiting for connection with client...")
conn, addr = s.accept()
print("Client is at", str(addr))

# Get the raw math equation from client.
client_data = conn.recv(100000)

# Decode the data to string.
decoded_data = client_data.decode()

# Split the lines into understandable characters,
# and make all the numbers integer.
splitted_eq = decoded_data.split(' ')
new_splitted_eq = []
for item in splitted_eq:
    try:
        new_splitted_eq.append(int(item))
    except ValueError:
        # If not a number, just append.
        new_splitted_eq.append(item)

# Use this variable, for knowing when to check for math signs.
last_was_num = False
done = False

final_result = 0
checking_signs = ['+', '-', '*', '/']

# Then, go through the new list.
for index, item in enumerate(new_splitted_eq):
    if type(item) == int:
        # Then it's a number.
        # Set last_was_num to True.
        last_was_num = True
        # Loop back.
        continue
    if last_was_num == True:
        # Check for math signs.
        for sign in checking_signs:
            if item == sign:
                if item == '+':
                    # Just add the last number to the final_result.
                    final_result += new_splitted_eq[index-1]

                    # Check that the index does not exceed the lists boundaries.
                    if index+2 < len(new_splitted_eq):
                        if new_splitted_eq[index+2] == new_splitted_eq[-1]:
                            # Then it's the last number in the list.
                            # Just add it, and break.
                            final_result += new_splitted_eq[index+2]
                            break
                    else:
                        # Then it's the last two numbers.
                        final_result += new_splitted_eq[index-1]
                        final_result += new_splitted_eq[-1]


# Print the final result, for now.
# Next step, is to send it back to the client.

# But there are unexpected outputs, 
# it's plussing the first number in the equation
# at the last iteration, so fx:
# 10 + 45 = 65
print(str(final_result))
```

The client `tmClient.py`:

```
"""
   This is the client that is sending the raw math equation
   to the server.
"""

import socket
import sys

import exceptions as exc

# Create socket.
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect to the server via. locahost.
host = '127.0.0.1'

# Try getting the port from the commandline.
try:
    port = int(sys.argv[1])
except IndexError:
    err = True
else:
    err = False

# If err is True, no argument is provided.
# Raise exception.
if err == True:
    msg = "You can't run this in the main or with no port argument!"
    raise exc.RunningInMainFileOrNoArgumentException(msg)

# Ask for connection.
s.connect((host, port))

# Ask for an equation by the user.
equation = input("Write an equation with spaces to seperate: ")

# Send the equation to the server, for evaluation.
s.send(str(equation).encode())

# Read the answer.
i = 0
# Make the final result an empty string.
eq_result = ''

while(True):
    # Ask for the data.
    # Allow the client to read up to 100.000 bytes.
    data = s.recv(100000)
    # To minimize lag, read the output in chunks.
    if i < 5:
        eq_result += str(data.decode())

    # If the output is done;
    # break out of loop.
    if not data:
        break

# Print the equations result.
if eq_result:
    print("The answer to " + equation + " is equal to " + eq_result)
else:
    print("No result has been returned. Please try again later.")

# Finally, terminate the connection with the server.
s.close()
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `if new_splitted_eq[index+2] == new_splitted_eq[-1]:` You use `index+2` wich will always be out of range when you get near the end of your array. Imagine you have 1 element in your array, at the first pass of the loop you will try to read the second element in your array, that does not exist.  Why are ou trying to get the `index+2` element?

Comment: @JulienRousé I use index+2 to get the next number after the mathematical sign. But yes, it will get out of range. I just don’t know what to do...

Comment: One possible solution would be to add a condition like `if index+2 < len(new_splitted_eq) ` before `if new_splitted_eq[index+2] == new_splitted_eq[-1]:`. Then you need to decide what to do in the `else` case

Comment: @JulienRousé Yea, I will do that and see if it works.

Comment: @JulienRousé I tried what you said, but it's not working yet. Now it doesn't throw an error, and almost performes the calculation right. But there is a slight problem; When you for example inputs: "10 + 45" It spits out the wrong answer. It says that the answer is 65, and that's not right. I have modified the question, to show the current code. What should I do?

Comment: It's because you  add your first number twice. Once `final_result += new_splitted_eq[index-1]` before the `if ... else ...` you just added, and once inside the `else`

Comment: @JulienRousé It's working! Thank you! If you answer this question now, i will mark you as the right.

Comment: It is still live problem?

Comment: if you are doing math computations only,there is a predefined function eval()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing a list with `if new_splitted_eq[index+2] == new_splitted_eq[-1]:` wich will always be out of bound if you don't check your index before. If for example your list has 1 item but you try to access the third element, you gonna get an error.

Since you edited your code to reflect the correction in my answer, a second problem is that you use `final_result += new_splitted_eq[index-1]` twice, once before the new `if else` and once inside the else branch, that's why you get the wrong result in your calculation.

Comment: Thanks for a very clear answer! I have marked your answer as the right one.